# Passing a list of arguments into a function in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**Note:** I recognize that similar questions about passing function arguments as a list have been asked previously, but most solutions rely on using `do.call` ahead of the function name and I have not had any luck with that approach.

I have a simple dashboard with two boxes on it. I would like to store the dropdown menu parameters as a list to be used in other boxes. The specific parameters I would like to store are: `icon`, and `width`.

Below is a working version of the application without the dropdown parameters stored in a list:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Box 1",
        dropdownMenu = dropdown(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                                width = "400px",
                                label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                                numericInput(inputId = "box1", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)
        )
    ),
    box(title = "Box 2",
        dropdownMenu = dropdown(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                                width = "400px",
                                label = "Plot Options Box 2",
                                numericInput(inputId = "box2", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

What I would like to do is store the box parameters in a list like this:

```
box_params <- list(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                   width = "400px")
```

And then to be able to call these parameters along these lines:

```
dropdown(box_params,
         label = "Plot Options Box 1",
         numericInput(inputId = "box1", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3))
```

Comment: when you say `do.call` is not working.  can you specify the issue.  I tried your original code without do.call and with do.call and couldn't find any difference though

Comment: I tried pretty much the solution that you posted a few min ago but couldn't get it to work. I don't remember specifically ever iteration of the code that I tried, but I wasn't successful

Comment: Just updated original post. It looks like `args` can take a list as its input, so I tried using `list_modify` to update the original list of parameters, but it's getting tripped up on the numericInput selector

Comment: my code was different than yours though `do.call("dropdown", c(box_params, 
                      label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                      numericInput(inputId = "box1", 
      label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)))`

Comment: Understand what you were asking for now. I just updated to show the error I'm getting. Thank you as always for your help. You've helped me with many questions previously and always appreciate the help

Comment: I am not sure about the error.  I undeleted the answer I posted with the full code along with the output I am getting

Comment: If the brackets are not matching, probably, it can end in some error

Comment: @DJC Please check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `do.call`

```
do.call("dropdown", c(box_params, 
                      label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                      numericInput(inputId = "box1", 
      label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)))
```

full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
box_params <- list(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                   width = "400px")



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Box 1",
        dropdownMenu = do.call("dropdown", c(box_params, list(label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                                                              numericInput(inputId = "box1", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3))))
    ),
    box(title = "Box 2",
        dropdownMenu = do.call("dropdown", c(box_params, list(label = "Plot Options Box 2",
                                                              numericInput(inputId = "box2", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3))))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

output:

[image]

Comment: @DJC this is your expected result? The dropdown button / icon isn't rendered.

Answer (score 3):

I will delete this:
but If i do:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

box_params <- list(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                   width = "400px")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Box 1",
        dropdownMenu = dropdown(box_params,
                                label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                                numericInput(inputId = "box1", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)
        )
    ),
    box(title = "Box 2",
        dropdownMenu = dropdown(box_params,
                                label = "Plot Options Box 2",
                                numericInput(inputId = "box2", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) { }

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get this:
[image]

So this is the same of @akrun's output?

Comment: Indeed - it seems both aren't working properly -  The dropdown button / icon isn't visible.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version which actually renders the dropdown menu (The `box()` function doesn't have a `dropdownMenu` argument as @DJC's example code suggests):

[image: result]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)

box_params <- list(icon = icon("cogs"), 
                   width = "400px")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    box(title = "Box 1",
        do.call(dropdown, c(box_params, 
                            list(label = "Plot Options Box 1",
                                 numericInput(inputId = "box1", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3))))
    ),
    box(title = "Box 2",
        dropdown(
          icon = icon("cogs"), 
          width = "400px",
          label = "Plot Options Box 2",
          numericInput(inputId = "box2", label = "Value", min = 1, max = 5, value = 3)
          
        )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I realized your approach in a former post, but was not sure what kind of soulution is expected. Beside I was wandering how do you construct the animated gif in your soulution. It is a cool feature in such cases to show.

Comment: Hi @TarJae - There is a bunch of free tools available to capture your screen and create a gif from it. I'm using [screentogif](https://www.screentogif.com/). Cheers